# /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory | Cannot use bundler, nor rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Just a disclaimer as I am pretty new to programming in general and decided to take upon ruby to make things happen, however...

I am following this tutorial/book I found online by Michael Hartl, but something happened a few days ago and I have been trying to fix it to no avail, and it is becoming incredibly disheartening.

The current issue is the title itself

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory
```

I cannot get past this, by now I have tried uninstalling RVM, Ruby and Rails (The last one is causing me trouble). 
I have even update ubuntu to 16LTS in my desperation; I have changed the first line of every file in /usr/local/bin to make it say

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

When I run

bundle install

I get:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory
```

which rails returns:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory
```

but when I run rails -v I get:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory
```

Again!!!
 I have zsh (if that makes any difference)

```
gem uninstall rails
```

gives me:

```
/usr/bin/gem: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/ruby2.3: no such file or directory
```

I have really tried multiple solution and none of them has worked, it probably has a very simple solution, but as said before I am a beginner, and although the constant troubleshooting must be educating, it is becoming incredibly frustrating and aversive.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: could you post the output of `ruby -v` and `which ruby`

Comment: That's the weird part, because rvm list gives me

    '=* ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]'


But 'ruby -v' gives me

    'command not found: ruby'

While 'which ruby' outputs

   'ruby not found'

Comment: Are you sure, that you have ruby in your PATH? What happens if you don't use `env`, but invoke Ruby explicitly to run your script, i.e. `/your/path/to/ruby your_script.rb` ?

Comment: zsh --login and then try again.
and do "rvm use 2.3 --default"

Comment: As I said, hate to sound like a newbie, but I am, and I do not know which one actually is my path. You mean the 'usr/bin/env'? because when I open that one folder manually, it does not have ANY .rb files, only some .py files (I have never installed Python before)

Comment: @IgorPavlov the 'rvm use 2.3 --default' gives me the output: 'Warning! PATH is not properly set up, 

''/home/federico/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles''

So user1934428 might be right, I still am unaware of how to apply this solution, though.

Comment: Take a look to [RVM faq](https://rvm.io/support/faq#rvm-is-not-found-or-the-rvm-selected-default-ruby-is-not-set-for-new-shells), you can see that probably you forgot adding RVM to the profile file.

Comment: @RafaelPorrasLucena I will check it out, but I think Zsh might be having something to do with it, because I followed the RVM installation throughout fully, maybe missed something...

Answer (score 8):

I faced same issue with following details

Ruby was installed on system

`which ruby` returned `/usr/local/bin/ruby`  but if is try to run any script from cron it was throwing error `/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory`

A little investigation revealed that env was trying to load ruby binary form `/usr/bin/ruby` even though `/usr/local/bin/` was in the `$PATH` env variable. So i created a soft link.

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

Now scripts can work from cron as well.

Comment: Can I ask how you concluded that env was trying to load the ruby binary from `/usr/bin/ruby`? I'm trying to investigate a similar issue so it would be great if you could explain your investigation.. :-)

Comment: Because shebang in ruby script is calling ruby like this.  "#!/usr/bin/env ruby"

Comment: In my case it was `sudo ln -s /home/NAME_OF_USER/.rbenv/shims/ruby /usr/bin/ruby` to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when I no longer trust that rvm is in a correct state, I start all over and reinstall rvm.  (More precise and less drastic fixes such as @IgorPavlov's --auto-dotfiles fix may work too.) Here are 3 ways to effectively deactivate the existing rvm installation; the first 2 blow away the ~/.rvm directory which contains rvm's rubies, gems, etc., and the 3rd just renames the directory so that rvm does not use it:

1) `rvm implode`

2) `rm -rf ~/.rvm`

3) `mv ~/.rvm ~/.rvm.bad`

This does not undo changes made to startup files, but that may be ok.

Then you reinstall rvm from scratch.

However, I believe you now have a bigger problem; you say "I have changed the first line of every file in /usr/local/bin to make it say

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

"

This was not good. ;)  Can you change those files back to their original content?

The `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` line's only purpose is to tell the shell that this script should be run by the command found in the path whose name is `ruby`.  The `env` command and the `/usr/bin` directory in which it lives have nothing to do with Ruby.  I suggest googling `/usr/bin/env` to better understand it.

If you want to automate the removal of the "shebang" lines from the files in /usr/bin, you can run the script below (but copy it to a directory other than /usr/bin, or it too will be modified).  You'll probably need to run the script with sudo, because the files in /usr/bin will probably be owned by root:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Removes #!/usr/bin/env ruby from files in /usr/bin.

require 'fileutils'

DIR = ARGV.first || '/usr/bin' #location can be overridden on cmd line

files = Dir[DIR + '/*'].select { |f| File.file?(f) }

files.each do |file|
  lines = File.readlines(file)
  needs_modifying = /^#!\/usr\/bin\/env\s+ruby$/ === lines.first
  puts (needs_modifying ? 'Modifying     ' : 'Not modifying ') + "#{file}."
  if needs_modifying
    FileUtils.cp(file, file + '.sav')
    File.write(file, lines[1..-1].join("\n"))
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh no, it's just so much on the internet you literally follow every possible solution... Wisdom comes with time, I assume, but how will I be able to restore these files with their original content? I mean, I can hardly remember what the exact lines were like.

Comment: How *exactly* did you edit those files?  Did you only add a first line that said `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`?  If so, there is a simple solution, and I can show you how.

Comment: I've added a script that fixes your files, and a paragraph of text before it, to the bottom of the answer.  I suggest backing up the directory somewhere before running this script. Note that the strategy of copying the original file to filename + '.sav' will not work if you run the script more than once; hence the suggestion to back up the files somewhere else.

Comment: @Keith_Bennett Something odd happened... I run your script and got the output '/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory'. But when I run 'ruby -v' it now returns 'ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]' Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest doing `rvm install ruby 2.3.0` again.  It might take a while but you can get a cup of coffee. ;)  In any case, that "shebang" line is merely a convenience that allows you to run the script without explicitly specifying the interpreter ('ruby') on the command line.  So while we get this sorted out, you should be able to run the script with `ruby [scriptname]`.

Comment: So, now, I did re-install ruby 2.3.0, and I also ran the script as you said, although I had to edit line 13 (you had an extra '='). The output was a very long list of "Not modifying [filenames]", so when I go to manually check /usr/local/bin all the files continue to have the same first line. However, now I believe that there is one problem left, and that is that when I ask 'rails -v', I receive:  /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>': undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError). Of course more issues may arise, but I believe this to be the main one.

Comment: When you reinstalled Ruby, rvm may have deleted that version's gems.  Try running `bundle` (you may need to `gem install bundler` first).  If that doesn't help, try `gem uninstall rails; gem install rails` to reinstall rails.

Comment: Funnily enough I also did not have the bundler, which I did before... But now I do again, however the output of any bundler action (install, update) returns '/home/federico/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb:356: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/federico/.rvm in PATH, mode 040777'. Federico being my user name; also, I don't know if I should solve that before running the last command, 'install rails', because 'uninstall rails' returns absolutely nothing, as if I only opened a directory. Thank you!

Comment: Bundler is a gem too so I'm not surprised it wasn't there.  You could run `sudo chmod go-w ` on the directory in question but at this point I'd probably just do an `rvm implode` and install rvm all over again.  It may take a while but is very little work for you.  I don't think this error will stop you from doing anything, but it's symptomatic of the weirdness that you might eliminate by reinstallation.

Comment: So you think that by reinstalling rvm the bundler issue would be solved? I sense we're near the end of the issue, however, thank you so much for your help, I realistically would have gone mad without the support, haha.

Comment: It would foolish for me to pretend to be certain that it would help, but given the cost/benefit, IMO even a low probability would make it worth the effort.  And you're very welcome.